# Streaming USB camera to RTSP stream using VLC or FFMPEG

Tags: camera, stream, usb, vlc, rtsp

I'd like to ask you for your help. I have camera ([endoscope](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/YPC-99-1M-Wifi-Wireless-Endoscope_60528569774.html)) connected using USB to my Mac and I would like to stream the video from camera using RTSP protocol (to my iOS app). I tried both FFMPEG and VLC but it does not work for me. But I have interesting partial results:

I can show the video from camera in VLC Player using this command:
`./VLC avcapture://0x14620000038f6001`
Everything works fine so far.

I can stream some local file to RTSP using this command:
* Using VLC: `./VLC Meeting.mov --sout "#rtp{sdp=sp://192.168.0.183:1234/live.sdp}"`
And everything also works fine.

But when trying to stream camera input to RTSP it doesn’t work: `./VLC avcapture://0x14620000038f6001 --sout "#rtp{sdp=sp://192.168.0.183:1234/live.sdp}”`
The problem is probably codec RV32. I tried also `#transcode` option but with no success:

`VLC media player 3.0.4 Vetinari (revision 3.0.4-0-gf615db6332)
[00007fbb2249a740] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[00007fbb20e13ff0] main libvlc error: interface "(null),none" initialization failed
[00007fbb20e13ff0] main libvlc: Spouštím přehrávač VLC s výchozím rozhraním. Přejete-li si spouštět přehrávač VLC bez rozhraní, použijte příkaz 'cvlc'.
[00007fbb22137b60] stream_out_rtp stream out: Consider passing --rtsp-host=IP on the command line instead.
[00007fbb22137b60] stream_out_rtp stream out error: cannot add this stream (unsupported codec: RV32)
[00007fbb26a264a0] main decoder error: cannot create packetizer output (RV32)`

Any ideas? Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks.